# How do I set Icicles’s default sort order for filenames?

Tags: minibuffer, icicles, filenames

In general, Icicles sorts things in alphabetical order. However, something I can’t find has made it so filenames are sorted in *descending* alphabetical order (z, y, x … b, a). I can use <kbd>C-M-,</kbd> to reverse it so it’s in ascending order. On the other hand, if I hit <kbd>C-,</kbd>, it says `(NOW: alphabetical)`; if I then select `alphabetical`, it changes to the correct order. The value of `icicle-sort-comparer` is `icicle-case-string-less-p`. My `custom.el` doesn’t contain any variables whose names include `icicle`.

I’m using [commit 9e9c37d from the GitHub mirror](https://github.com/emacsmirror/icicles/commit/9e9c37d2a54771c635d00d1fe171cef5eab4d95d) right now, but I’ve been seeing this for a while now, just wasn’t thinking about it.

How can I make it so Icicles sorts filenames (e.g. in `icicle-find-file`) in ascending alphabetical order by default?

Answer (score 1):

Updating this to provide the short answer, after email exchange:

Set user option **`icicle-file-sort`** to the sort order you want, e.g., `icicle-case-string-less-p`.

(Leaving the rest of the original response, below, in case it helps someone.)

---

I'm not sure what's going on, so this isn't much of an "answer", so far.  You can follow up by email if this becomes a back-and-forth (not good for emacs.SE) - use **`M-x icicle-send-bug-report`** for that. That's probably the best recourse. (You might want to start with that, and ultimately delete the question here or add an answer.)

It's presumably not important, but I guess you have some custom key bindings, because neither `` C-M-` `` nor `` C-` `` is bound by Icicles by default.  It sounds like you've maybe bound `` C-` `` to `icicle-change-sort-order` (which is `C-,` by default).  I guess you did that by customizing `icicle-completion-key-bindings`.  But you say that you have no customizations (no occurrences of `icicle` in your `custom-file`).  So this is one thing that's unclear to me.

Do I understand the problem correctly to be this?

- By default, when using `icicle-find-file` (for example), Icicles tells you that sorting is `alphabetical`, but the order is z-to-a, not a-to-z.  Does this happen also for other completion, besides file-name completion?
- If you then use `icicle-change-sort-order` (`C-,` by default) during completion, to change the order, and you pick `alphabetical`, the problem is corrected (sorting becomes a-to-z).  Does it then stay corrected, so that the next time you use `icicle-find-file` (or another completing command) the order is a-to-z?

*Here are some things to check:*

- Can you reproduce the problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file, so no use of `custom-file`)?  If so, please send a recipe to reproduce the problem: **`M-x icicle-send-bug-report`**.
- If not, start by bisecting your init file (which might then mean bisecting `custom-file`), to find what is creating the problem.
- Is either `icicle-reverse-sort-p` or `icicle-reverse-multi-sort-p` non-`nil`? (If so, what is it?)  If so, try resetting it to its initial value of `nil`, and see if you can find out where it gets set to non-`nil` (starting with your init file).
- The value of option `icicle-sort-orders-alist`.  You can modify it, but see the doc string.  This is the default value, after you've loaded Icicles (it's not the value shown in the `defcustom`, which is `nil`):

```lisp
    (("turned OFF")
     ("by abbrev frequency" . icicle-command-abbrev-used-more-p)
     ("by previous use alphabetically" . icicle-historical-alphabetic-p)
     ("by last use as input" . icicle-latest-input-first-p)
     ("by directories last" . icicle-dirs-last-p)
     ("by directories first" . icicle-dirs-first-p)
     ("by last use, dirs first" . icicle-dirs-and-latest-use-first-p)
     ("by file type" . icicle-file-type-less-p)
     ("by last file modification time" . icicle-latest-modification-first-p)
     ("by last file access time" . icicle-latest-access-first-p)
     ("by last use" . icicle-latest-use-first-p)
     ("by 2nd parts alphabetically" . icicle-2nd-part-string-less-p)
     ("case insensitive" . icicle-case-insensitive-string-less-p)
     ("proxy candidates first" . icicle-proxy-candidate-first-p)
     ("extra candidates first" . icicle-extra-candidates-first-p)
     ("special candidates first" . icicle-special-candidates-first-p)
     ("by flx score" . icicle-flx-score-greater-p)
     ("alphabetical" . icicle-case-string-less-p))
```

HTH.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: My apologies, I *am* using the default keybindings but for some reason I went to great lengths to put backticks in the question. ‍♂️ You’ve correctly understood the problem. This only happens for file-name completion. Picking `alphabetical` doesn’t fix the order for future invocations. The `icicle-reverse…` variables you mentioned are `nil`. I’ll try your suggestions. And thank you for writing a really great library in the first place!

Comment: Good. Please follow up with `M-x icicle-send-bug-report`, providing a recipe, preferably starting from `emacs -Q`, if you don't find the answer easily. I can't repro it, so far.